# "Order! Order!" Is this the only call the Speaker of the House of Commons is allowed when calling for MPs attention?

Tags: united-kingdom, house-of-commons

For anyone following the UK political developments in recent months, the role of the Speaker of the House of Commons, John Bercow, might have received special attention. His calls for "[order, order](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWSHXlpmwso)" are particularly well-known.

The question is simple. Is this call for MPs attention the (only) official way to do so? Or is it merely a custom which depends on the style of the speaker? For instance, could he instead use words like "attention", or "silence", or etc?

I've watch several videos of previous speakers and they all use the same expression, "order". Some examples [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXWLTD4_oYU), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wv-eX-1y6Uc), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_p5t4rPQ44), and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yrzsh52l9HY).

Comment: Even in the link you give, he says words that are not "order" so it seems fairly clear he is not limited to those particular syllables.

Comment: @BryanKrause To call the attention of MPs **for the first time**? Can you point to the video and time, please?

Comment: Luchonacho - why "notorious"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=EY7EIZl4raY (from [here](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/jan/17/more-animal-than-ever-europeans-find-joy-in-john-bercow))

Comment: Luchonacho - I have viewed the clip and cannot see why you used the pejorative "notorious". Do you actually understand what the word means?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Mmm, no idea the word had a particularly negative connotation. [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/notorious) suggests that's typically the case. I was tricked by the [Spanish equivalent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/notorio#Spanish), which doesn't have such negative connotation. Updated.

Comment: @luchonacho: interesting aside on the difference with Spanish. You can read about how the nickname "the Notorious RBG" was somewhat jokingly applied to the US Supreme Court Justice, as if she was a gangster rapper with a long list of heavy convictions.

Answer (score 4):

The speaker is calling for order as opposed to disorder. The phrase is, so far as I know, a traditional one.

The [role](https://www.parliament.uk/business/commons/the-speaker/the-role-of-the-speaker/role-of-the-speaker/) is broader than that though.

> The Speaker is perhaps best known as the person who keeps order and calls MPs to speak during Commons debates. The Speaker calls MPs in turn to give their opinion on an issue. MPs signal that they want to speak by standing up from their seat (a custom known as 'catching the Speaker's eye') or they can notify the Speaker in advance by writing.
>
> The Speaker has full authority to make sure MPs follow the rules of the House during debates. This can include:
>
> - directing an MP to withdraw remarks if, for example, they use abusive language
> - suspending the sitting of the House due to serious disorder
> - suspending MPs who are deliberately disobedient - known as naming
> - asking MPs to be quiet so Members can be heard